# Why is address sanitizer not indicating a memory leak after malloc() memory was not freed?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

(I did not write this code, my professor did...)
I was looking at some code that my professor wrote and it all made sense to me, except for one thing. (Because we were running out of time, he did not bother to free any of the memory), however, he was compiling with address sanitizer on. But when he ran the code, no address sanitizer error warning was shown?

We were running `gcc 9.3` on an Ubuntu machine. When I comment out the `add_line` function, it throws leaks, only for `crnt`. I guess `lines` does not throw a memory leak because it was declared in the global space? But why doesn't `crnt` throw a memory leak when the `add_line` function is called?

(Also, here are the compile flags that are used.
`-g -std=c99 -Wall -Wvla -fsanitize=address,undefined`)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEBUG 1

#define BUFSIZE 8
#define LISTLEN 16

char **lines;
int line_count, line_array_size;

void add_line(char *p)
{
    if (DEBUG) printf("Adding |%s|\n", p);
    if (line_count == line_array_size) {
    line_array_size *= 2;
    lines = realloc(lines, line_array_size * sizeof(char *));
    // TODO: check whether lines is NULL
    }

    lines[line_count] = p;
    line_count++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd, bytes;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    char *crnt;
    int len;
    int pos, start;

    // TODO: move array list management to separate functions
    lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * LISTLEN);
    if (!lines) {
    printf("malloc failed\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    line_array_size = LISTLEN;
    line_count = 0;

    if (argc > 1) {
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    } else {
    fd = 0;
    }

    crnt = NULL;
    len = 0;
    while ((bytes = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
    // read buffer and break file into lines

    start = 0;
    for (pos = 0; pos < bytes; pos++) {
        if (buf[pos] == '\n') {
        if (crnt == NULL) {
            len = pos - start;
            crnt = malloc(len + 1);
            memcpy(crnt, &buf[start], len);
        } else {
            len += pos;
            crnt = realloc(crnt, len + 1);
            memcpy(&crnt[len - pos], buf, pos);
        }
        crnt[len] = '\0';
        // add_line(crnt); <------------- When I uncomment this line, no address-sanitizer leak is detected. With this line commented, asan does throw a leak only for the crnt variable. Why is that?
        crnt = NULL;
        start = pos + 1;
        }
    }

    if (start < pos) {
        if (crnt == NULL) {
        len = pos - start;
        crnt = malloc(len + 1);
        memcpy(crnt, &buf[start], len);
        } else {
        int newlen = len + (pos - start);
        crnt = realloc(crnt, newlen + 1);
        memcpy(&crnt[len], &buf[start], pos - start);
        len = newlen;
        }
        crnt[len] = '\0';  // technically unnecessary
    }
    }
    if (bytes == -1) {
    perror("read");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // if we reach here, we have read the entire file
    // sort and print the list
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After further research, I found this issue on GitHub https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/937 ... Because `add_line` is storing a pointer passed to it by `main`, the two stack frames now over lap and `lsan` is simply unable to detect such an issue as a contributor explained in the issue above.

Comment: That's an interesting bug report but it has nothing to do with your question. Which two stack frames do you think overlap? `main's` stack frame doesn't overlap with anything, and `add_line`'s stack frame is irrelevant, afaics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the definition of "memory leak". I would have liked to have quoted a section in LeakSanitizer's documentation where it offers a clear and precise definition of the concept, which seems fundamental to its operation, but I couldn't find one, so you'll have to bear with a bit of projection on my part.

A region of dynamically allocated (i.e. with `malloc` or friends) memory has leaked when there is no possible way for it to be `free`d. In other words, if your program allocates memory and throws away the address before the allocation has been free'd, the memory has leaked.

That's subtly different from what you might think the definition is. You might think that memory has leaked if your program terminates without freeing every block of memory it allocated. That's certainly a possible definition, and I'm not going to criticise it (much), but it's actually not very precise.

At what point has the program terminated? It hasn't really terminated when `main()` returns, because you might still have clean-up functions registered with `atexit()`, and those functions don't execute until *after* `main()` returns. (Or when `exit()` is called, which is effectively the same thing.) It's actually pretty common (though, to my mind, pointless) to use `atexit()` functions precisely in order to `free()` objects which might not have been deallocated before `exit()`.

OK, you can't check whether a memory allocation has been freed by checking whether it has been `free`d when `main` returns. If you want to do it that way, you need to defer the test until really the last possible moment. But at what's really the last possible moment, the process is about to cease to exist and the operating system is going to reclaim all the memory used by the process, including whatever resources were acquired by the memory allocation library. So at the last possible moment, there is no memory leak, because there is no memory.

(There are embedded systems which have no concept of separate processes memory, etc., and so what I wrote up there might not apply to *every possible computation system*. But it applies to everything on which AddressSanitizer is implemented.)

A key point is that the `atexit()` handler needs to be able to find the objects it is cleaning up, and since it executes after `main()` has terminated, it cannot use any automatic (i.e. stack-allocated) object. Only objects with static lifetime are available to it. So for it to be able to do its task, the address of the object to be cleaned up on termination must be stored in global memory. If the region's memory is not stored somewhere persistent, the memory has leaked (as per my definition above) and we don't actually have to wait to see whether an `atexit` manages to `free` the memory.

Which brings us back to what I claim is a workable definition of a memory leak: dynamically allocated memory whose address is no longer present in the executable. That memory region can no longer be used, so it's garbage, but it cannot be `free`d because there the program doesn't know what its address is.

Your `lines` array is a global variable. Indeed, you point that out in your question:

> I guess `lines` does not throw a memory leak because it was declared in the global space?

That's correct. `lines` is a global variable, so its contents are still accessible even after `main()` returns. Not only are its contents accessible, so is any memory pointed to by some object in the array it points to. You could, if you wanted to, `free` the saved lines in an `atexit` handler:

```c
void cleanup(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < line_count; ++i) { free(lines[i]); }
  free(lines);
}
```

(To use that, you only need to call `atexit(cleanup)` just after you initialise `lines` and `line_count`.)

So that brings us to:

> But why doesn't `crnt` throw a memory leak when the `add_line` function is called?

`crnt` contains the address of a dynamically-allocated buffer which contains the current line. If you call `add_line(crnt)`, that pointer is stored in `lines`. So it's available for the clean-up function, as above. You can set `crnt` to `NULL` at your convenience, because it is no longer the only pointer to that buffer.

But if you don't call `add_line`, then `crnt` *is* the only pointer to that buffer and when you set `crnt` to `NULL`, there is no longer a pointer to the buffer. The buffer has leaked and AddressSanitizer is there to tell you about it. (AddressSanitizer would have caught the problem even if you hadn't set `crnt` to `NULL`, because `crnt` ceases to exist when `main()` returns or calls `exit()`, and at that point the address has been lost. Or if you overwrite `crnt` with a different allocation's address.)

For a much simpler example, try these two very similar programs:

#### Memory leak

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  void* megabyte = malloc(1<<20);
  (void)megabyte; /* Suppress unused variable warning */
}
```

#### No memory leak

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void* megabyte;
int main(void) {
  megabyte = malloc(1<<20);
}
```

---

Note that the Valgrind memcheck tool *can* report on memory, like `megabyte` in the second example, which is never `free`d even though it is still reachable at what Valgrind considers the end of execution. But it doesn't do so by default. If you run Valgrind on the second program with the flags `--show-leak-kinds=all --leak-check=full`, it will report that a megabyte of memory is "still reachable". (To try valgrind, you have to compile the program without AddressSanitizer, I believe. The two tools are not completely compatible.)

Comment: Wow... That is an incredible answer and really clears things up for me. Thank you so much!